# Concatenated text in selector

Tags: jquery, html, concatenation, selector, parent-child

So, here's the problem I'm having. `depth` is a variable between 1 and 5. Lets say it's 2 at the point that this code runs.  I'm trying to select the child of an `li` element with the class `depth-2`.  So ideally, the selector would look like `$('li.depth-2 > a[data-listIsExpanded="false"]')`...and the rest doesn't really matter, because I'm pretty sure it's right.  I just need to know the proper syntax for selecting the child of a concatenated string. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$('"li.depth-"+depth > a[data-listIsExpanded="false"]').attr('data-listIsExpanded','true').parent().find('>ul').slideDown('medium');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need

```
$('li.depth-' + depth + ' > a[data-listIsExpanded="false"]').attr('data-listIsExpanded','true').parent().find('>ul').slideDown('medium');
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it all needed to be a string.